# Is SEO effected when URL changes from .php to not including .php

Tags: php, url, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO - Changing file extension](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11525/seo-changing-file-extension)

Hi,

Is SEO effected when URL changes from .php to not including `.php`? For example, if you change a URL from `example.com/about.php` to`example.com/about`, do you lose the earlier SEO impact?

I am replacing an older website, and want to keep the URL the same for SEO purposes. The problem is that the older URL includes .php at the end.

I'm replacing the website with a new WordPress site, and when I add the `.php`) to the URL, the formatting is disrupted. I can create a URL that is the same, but I can't add the `.php` at the end.

Does anyone know how I could add .php to the URL without having the format be interrupted?

Answer (score 2):

Do a .htaccess 301 redirect:

```
redirect 301 /about.php http://www.example.com/about
```

This'll tell browsers to update their bookmarks, inform search engines of changes, and just generally get things moving to the new url.

Comment: or more generally: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php http://www.example.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]`